# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 398: invalid start byte || book python for everyone

Tags: python, linux, sockets, webserver

hey am trying to pull image from web server using socket programming in python while going through python for everyone book there is example in networked programming chapter i copied the code from example ***urljpeg.py***

```
import socket 
import time 
#HOST = 'data.pr4e.org'
#PORT = 80

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))

mysock.sendall(b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/cover3.jpg HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
count = 0
picture = b""

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(5120)
    if len(data) < 1: break
# time .sleep(0.25)
    count = count + len(data)
    print( len(data),count)
    picture = picture + data

mysock.close()


# look for the end of the header (2crlf)

pos = picture.find(b"r\n\r\n")
print("Header length ", pos)
print(picture[:pos].decode())

# skip pasr the header and save the picture data
picture = picture[pos+4:]
fhand = open("stuff.jpg","wb")
fhand.write(picture)
fhand.close()
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means, at the most fundamental level? Which line of code that is causing it? What that line of code is trying to do, and why? (Hint: the root cause is a fairly simple typo, an omitted character.)

Comment: actually i am learning and  new to python  i was just going through book python for everyone  it says line 29 :: `print(picture[:pos].decode())`  == where picture as a variable hold bytes and to print the byte from index 0 to pos = position should i put a parenthesis form before picture to .decode

Comment: sir am really having hard time to understand the issue

Comment: so we get encoding error when the file we are pulling is not utf8 encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are trying to decode data which is not utf-8. So why is this happening? Let's take a step back and look at what the code is doing:

```
# look for the end of the header (2crlf)
pos = picture.find(b"r\n\r\n")
print("Header length ", pos)
print(picture[:pos].decode())
```

We're trying to find a sequence of \r\n\r\n, i.e. CR LF CR LF in the data. This would be the empty line that separates the HTTP header (which should be in ASCII, which is a subset of UTF-8) from the actual image data. Then we try to decode everything up to that point as a string. So why does it fail? The program conveniently prints the header length, and in the bit you posted earlier we could see that this was -1, which means that the `picture.find` call did not find anything! Why not? Well, look carefully at what the code actually does:

```
# look for the end of the header (2crlf)
pos = picture.find(b"r\n\r\n")
```

It should be looking for `\r\n\r\n`, but it is actually looking for `r\n\r\n`!

Comment: fo i forgot to put a  back slash in front of r   which should be equal to CR thanks a lot man you answered way more than i expected , i  would have never new what is CR ans LF is and the bit i posted an an output was in answer segment so some one deleted it.